# Append dynamic li from an array

Tags: javascript

I have been spoiled by frameworks and would like to know how plain ol' Javascript handles this. Basically, I would like my JavaScript to output a list that contains all items from my array. The code is as follows:

**javascript**

```
function addrain(){
    var element = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'];
    for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++){ 
    //what goes here??//
    document.getElementById('listcontent').append...
});
}
```

**html**

```
<ul id="listcontent"></ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to create elements, [`element.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to fill them with text and [`parent.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to add it to its parent element.

You can also use [`element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) or [`element.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) instead of [`element.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) if you want your `<li>` elements to contain more HTML than just plain text.

Here's an runnable example, based on your code:

```js
function addrain() {
  var element = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'];
  for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
    // Create DOM element
    var li = document.createElement('li');
        
    // Set text of element
    li.textContent = element[i];

    // Append this element to its parent
    document.getElementById('listcontent').appendChild(li);
  }
}

addrain();
```

```html
<ul id="listcontent"></ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to create a DOM element for each item, and then append that element to your list.

```js
function addrain(){
    var element = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'];
    for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++){ 

      // Create DOM element
      let childNode = document.createElement('li');

      // Set content to current element
      childNode.innerHTML = element[i];

      // Add DOM Node to list
      document.getElementById('listcontent').appendChild(childNode);
    }
}

addrain();
```

```html
<ul id="listcontent"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this as your function:

```
function addrain(){
    var element = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'];
    for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++){ 
        var li = document.createElement('li'); // Create an <li>
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(element[i])); // Add the name of the fruit
        document.getElementById('listcontent').appendChild(li); // Append the <li> to the <ul>
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xcqegL3b/

Answer (score 0):

```js
const elements = ["orange", "apple", "banana"];

const list_element_to_insert = document.getElementById('listcontent'); // get the html element

// i have used mapping first to create a li element. then transform the 
// returned map list into string by join
list_element_to_insert.innerHTML = `${elements.map(element => `<li>${element}</li>`).join('')}`;
```

```html
<ul id="listcontent"></ul>
```